# vue default redirect causing maximum stack error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So I have this section of my vue-router that's causing an issue:

```
{
    component: Tutorial,
    name: "tutorial",
    path: "/tutorial/:page?",
    redirect: "/tutorial/0",
},
```

If I remove the redirect, the issue is gone. There's no children for this route path either. Is it not possible to assign a default param value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a default value in `redirect` part. It will go to `/tutorial/0`, next it will redirect to `/tutorial/0` again and again...

If you want to set a default param value. You can implement it in the `Tutorial` component.

For example:

```
// In Tutorial component
beforeRouteEnter() {
    this.$route.params.page = this.$route.params.page ? this.$route.params.page : 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because `"/tutorial/0"` matches `"/tutorial/:page?"` too.

Since the router configs is First In First out,

you can define your routes like this

```
    {
      component: Tutorial,
      name: 'tutorial',
      path: '/tutorial/0'
    },
    {
      path: '/tutorial/:page?',
      redirect: '/tutorial/0'
    }
```

if the current route matches `/tutorial/0`, it will render your component. If it doesn't match `/tutorial/0`, Vue will check if it matches `/tutorial/:page?` and do the redirection if it matches.